# How to use function instead of class in Nextjs custom document for Styled Components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I'm using NextJS and Styled Components. Reading the documentation below I added a custom _document.js in NextJS to make Styled Components works.

[Styled Components Doc](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#nextjs)

The example code is written in a React Class, is there a way of converting this to a function?

Comment: you can always convert a class component to a function one, thing is, based on your question I think you're not familiar with React class component style, you should go read to docs first, then when you're comfortable with both styles, you can do everything effortlessly.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing so as it's not currently supported by Next.js: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19355.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible since [Next 11.1.1](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v11.1.1), thanks to [#28515](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/28515), but the feature seems currently undocumented.
See an example below:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

const Document = () => (
  <Html>
    <Head/>
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
)

export default Document
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there is no good way to do it, I guess you could somehow override it but Next.js uses _document and _app for in its custom runtime and it is not a good idea to override it.

_document's purpose:

> A custom Document is commonly used to augment your application's <html> and <body> tags.

Also, note that using any logic (apart from this inside getInitialProps) inside _document is unadvisable: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document#caveats